# Exploding a data frame row by row and storing the exploded values in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have the following code.

I want to go through the 'outlierdataframe' dataframe **row by row** and **explode the values** in the 'x' and 'y' columns.

For each exploded row, I then want to store this exploded row as its own **dataframe**, with **columns 'newID', 'x' and 'y'**.

However, the following code prints **everything in one column** rather than printing the **exploded 'x' values in one column**, the **exploded 'y' values in another column**?

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
individualframe = outlierdataframe.iloc[0]
individualoutliers = individualframe.explode(list('xy'))
newframe = pd.DataFrame(individualoutliers)
print(newframe)
```

outlier dataframe first line:

[image]

indexing first line of outlier dataframe:

```
outlierdataframe.iloc[0]

index                                                      24
subID                                         Prolific_610020
level                                                       1
complete                                                False
duration                                            20.015686
map_view                                            12.299759
distance                                           203.426697
x           [55, 55, 55, 60, 60, 60, 65, 70, 70, 75, 80, 8...
y           [60, 60, 60, 60, 65, 65, 70, 70, 75, 75, 80, 8...
r           [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1...
batch                                                       1
newID                                                  610020
Name: 24, dtype: object
```

```
newframe = pd.DataFrame(individualoutliers)
print(newframe)

                24
0                 24
1    Prolific_610020
2                  1
3              False
4          20.015686
..               ...
121               55
122               55
123               55
124                1
125           610020
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to explode your selected (`list`) columns (e.g, `x` and `y`).

Try this :

```
out = (
        df
          .loc[:, ["newID", "x", "y"]]
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).explode())
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

    newID    x    y
0  610020  100   60
0  610020   55   60
0  610020   55   60
0  610020   60   60
0  610020   60   65
0  610020   60   65
0  610020   65   70
0  610020   70   70
0  610020   70   75
0  610020   75   75
0  610020   80   80
```

If you need to assign a single dataframe (with a patter name, `df_newID`) for each group, use this:

```
for k, g in out.groupby("newID"):
    globals()['df_' + str(k)] = g
    
print(df_610020, type(df_610020))

    newID    x    y
0  610020  100   60
0  610020   55   60
0  610020   55   60
0  610020   60   60
0  610020   60   65
0  610020   60   65
0  610020   65   70
0  610020   70   70
0  610020   70   75
0  610020   75   75
0  610020   80   80 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that works too! :) What is the need for the 'globals()'?

Comment: To create a variable with a name based on a string. And that’s what you need, you need a single dataframe for each newID.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works:

```
individualframe = outlierdataframe.iloc[0]
individualoutliers1 = individualframe[['x']].explode('x')
individualoutliers2 = individualframe[['y']].explode('y')
newIDs = individualframe[['newID']][0]
individualoutliers1 = pd.DataFrame(individualoutliers1)
individualoutliers2 = pd.DataFrame(individualoutliers2)
data = [individualoutliers1,individualoutliers2]
newframe = pd.concat(data,axis=1)
newframe = newframe.rename(columns={newframe.columns.values[0]:'x',newframe.columns.values[1]:'y'})
newframe['newID'] = newIDs 
print(newframe)


Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
      y    y   newID
0    55   60  610020
1    55   60  610020
2    55   60  610020
3    60   60  610020
4    60   65  610020
5    60   65  610020
6    65   70  610020
```